# In Drools, what does it mean to compare IDs

Tags: drools, optaplanner, drools-planner

I understand the basics of writing drools rules now but i can't seem to understand in the examples that i've seen (optaplanner), there are comparisons of IDs. Is this necessary? Why is it there?

```
// RoomOccupancy: Two lectures in the same room at the same period.
// Any extra lecture in the same period and room counts as one more violation.
rule "roomOccupancy"
    when
        Lecture($leftId : id, period != null, $period : period, room != null, $room : room)
        // $leftLecture has lowest id of the period+room combo
        not Lecture(period == $period, room == $room, id < $leftId)
        // rightLecture has the same period
        Lecture(period == $period, room == $room, id > $leftId, $rightId : id)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

From my understanding deleting the line with `not Lecture(..` and leaving `Lecture(period == $period, room == $room)` should do the trick. Is my understanding correct or am I missing some use cases here?

Comment: Try your change, you'll see what's the problem (same lecture matches both Lecture patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that a pattern such as

```
$a: Lecture()
$b: Lecture()
```

with two Lecture facts A an B in the system will produce the following matches and firings:

```
$a-A, $b-B   (1)
$a-B, $b-A   (2)
$a-A, $b-A
$a-B, $b-B
```

Therefore, to reduce the unwanted combinations you need have a way to ascertain to have not identical facts matching (bound to) $a and $b:

```
$a: Lecture( $ida: id )
$b: Lecture( $idb: id != $ida )
```

However, using not equal still produces combinations (1) and (2).

Answer (score 1):

Given 2 queens A and B, the id comparison in the "no 2 queens on the same horizontal row" constraint makes sure that we only match A-B and not B-A, A-A and B-B.

Same principle for lectures.